# Any way to have different materials in instances collection in the current Blender version?

Tags: materials, instances, collections

I`ve seen a few similar questions but as Blender constantly changes I thought I would ask again. I have instance collection (no geometry nodes) to save computer resources. Same geometry but need different materials and textures. Is there a way to do it? I dont need random colors but rather assinging materials in a normal way. Here is the example.[image]